# Erase logs of kite (Atom plugin) is safe?

Tags: atom-editor, kite

Recently I found a large log file of kite's Atom plugin. The file `C:\Users\cmcuervol\AppData\Local\Kite\logs\client.log.2019-10-10_11-55-44-AM.bak`, have a size of **2.7 GB**, the OS is Windows 10. Moreover, in the folder `C:\Users\ccuervo\AppData\Local\Kite\logs\`, are locate two other files `client.log` and `client.log.2019-10-25_08-23-42-AM.bak`, with sizes of 48.3 and 25.7 MB respectively.

I want free the storage of the large file, but conserving the kite functionlaties, I don't know if this file is important for kite performance.